# How to get information from Excel files using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I am new to SSIS and am trying to understand how to do the following:

I have a folder (TestFolder) that has multiple folders within it (SubFolder1, SubFolder2, etc). In each subfolder there are multiple Excel files that have various names but will end in a date (Formatted as YYYYMM). In each Excel workbook there is a tab named: AccessRates and this is the data I want to store in the table in SQL Server.

Okay, so the question: How do I set up my SSIS Control flow to handle such a task? I have built a Data Flow Task that handles the Data conversion, error handling and ultimate placement in the server table, but I can not figure out the Control Flow. I believe I need a ForEach loop container, but I can't figure out how to set it, along with the variables up.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution guidelines

You should follow these steps:

1. Use a foreach loop and enumerate on files.
2. Set the top folder and select traverse subfolders.
3. Set the file sequence something like [the start of all files]*.xlsx
4. Retrieve fully qualified file name and map to a variable.
5. Inside foreach, drop a dataflow task
6. Make an Excel connection to any of the files
7. Go to the properties of the connection (F4).
8. Set an expression map connection string to the variable from step 4
9. Set Delay Validation to true.
10. Do your data flow.

This should be it.

## Step-by-step tutorials

There are many articles that describe the whole process step-by-step, you can refer to them if you need more details:

- [How to read data from multiple Excel files with SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [Loop Through Excel Files in SSIS](https://mikedavissql.com/2013/09/16/loop-through-excel-files-in-ssis/)
- [Loop through Excel Files and Tables by Using a Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/loop-through-excel-files-and-tables-by-using-a-foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Hadi. Thanks for the top up with links et al.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/) it shows you how to set up an environment var to store the sheet name you want to get the data from and then how to use that to get the data from an excel source.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like the link but he's not asking about multiple sheets with unknown names. It's a specific sheet from unknown spreadsheets with a common-ish name.

Comment: Correct, but he can use the info in the link to learn how to set the sheet name in the SSIS package.